# sympy.simplify: custom measure does not find optimal expression

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I am looking to create an expression measure for sympy.simplify that generally results in more readable expressions. However, I cannot seem to prevent sympy from applying the sqrt operation to individual factors of its operand in spite of my measure.

My current measure implementation (based on [the docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/simplification.html#simplify)) is the following:

```
import sympy as sp
def my_measure(expr):
    """A readable expression metric. Prefer MUL/DIV
    over ADD/SUB over POW."""
    # Break expression into a sum of its operations
    count = sp.count_ops(expr, visual=True)
    # Weight specific operations
    count = count.subs(sp.Symbol("POW"), 10)
    count = count.subs(sp.Symbol("ADD"), 3)
    count = count.subs(sp.Symbol("SUB"), 3)
    # Every other operation gets a weight of 1 (the default)
    count = count.replace(sp.Symbol, type(sp.S.One))
    return count
```

I get an unexpected result when I try to display an expression of the form sqrt(ab)
with a > 0, b > 0.

```
>>> a, b = sp.symbols("a b", positive=True)
>>> exp = sp.sqrt(a*b)
>>> simp_exp = sp.simplify(exp, ratio=1.0, measure=my_measure)
>>> sp.pretty_print(exp)
√a⋅√b
>>> print(my_measure(exp))
23
>>> sp.pretty_print(simp_exp)
√a⋅√b
>>> print(my_measure(simp_exp))
23
```

The measure is working correctly: each sqrt operation is internally (x**(1/2)), i.e., 1 POW and 1 DIV, so a cost of 11. Each MUL is 1 point so that gives 23 total for sqrt(a) * sqrt(b). Clearly,
however, a less costly representation is sqrt(a*b) which would result in a score of 12.

Note that for some reason this only occurs when the "positive" condition is imposed. Removing this condition gives the expected result.

```
>>> a, b = sp.symbols("a b")
>>> exp = sp.sqrt(a*b)
>>> simp_exp = sp.simplify(exp, ratio=1.0, measure=my_measure)
>>> sp.pretty_print(exp)
   _____
 ╲╱ a⋅b
>>> print(my_measure(exp))
12
>>> sp.pretty_print(simp_exp)
    _____
  ╲╱ a⋅b
>>> print(my_measure(simp_exp))
12
```

Unless I am missing something, the positive assumptions should have nothing to do with the simplification process because all complex multiplication (real, positive, or otherwise) would obey the same exponent rule, a^n * b^n = (a*b)^n.

Even more strange: choosing n=2 results in the same unexpected result for either the positive or complex case.

```
>>> a, b = sp.symbols("a b")
>>> exp = (a*b)**2
>>> simp_exp = sp.simplify(exp, ratio=1.0, measure=my_measure)
>>> sp.pretty_print(exp)
 2  2
a ⋅b
>>> print(my_measure(exp))
21
>>> sp.pretty_print(simp_exp)
 2  2
a ⋅b
>>> print(my_measure(simp_exp))
21
```

So I have a few questions:

1. Why can't sympy.simplify find the optimal expression given my measure?
2. Why do exponents get distributed to the factors of their operands before any simplification is requested?
3. Why would assuming the factors are positive and real change anything?
4. Any advice on getting the behavior I'm looking for?

I am running python version 3.9.18 and sympy version 1.12.

Thanks!

Comment: The positive assumption affects this because `sqrt(a)*sqrt(b) = sqrt(a*b)` does not hold for negative numbers.

Comment: Ah okay yes, that does make sense ( such as if both a and b are negative ). I guess I am only wondering then why the simplification does not occur when a,b are positive and real.

Comment: Autosimplification will write a product of positive values as the product of the individual square roots.

Comment: @smichr do you know where this autosimplification is documented / occurs or of any means to prevent it? So far seems like the only solution is to manually traverse the expression tree and sort things out if a > 0 b > 0.

Comment: There is not a good way to just disable it since it is built into the eval method of a function. Without more information I would suggest just not using assumptions on the variables.